# onclick passing data to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link that when clicked should assign a rails variable to a JavaScript variable. The JavaScript is then used to calculate the price. I have the price calculated with a hard coded value at the moment.

in the html I need `data-price` to be `var blankPrice` in the js. Any help would be great.

```js
$("a.shirt-color-link").on("click", function(){
  calculatePrice($(this));
})
 function calculatePrice(){

  var blankPrice = obj.attr("data-price");


  console.log(blankPrice)
  var pricePerSide = 3;

  var printedSides = 0;

  if (frontCanvas) {
   var frontCanvasJson = JSON.parse(frontCanvas);
  
  if (frontCanvasJson && frontCanvasJson.objects.length > 0)
   printedSides++;
  }

  if (backCanvas) {
  var backCanvasJson = JSON.parse(backCanvas);

   if (backCanvasJson && backCanvasJson.objects.length > 0)
    printedSides++;
  }

  var total = blankPrice + (pricePerSide * printedSides);
  $('.base-price').text('$' + total);
 }
```

```html
<a 
   tabindex="-1" 
   data-original-title="<%= shirt_color.color_name.titleize %>"
   class="shirt-color-link" 
   data-color="#<%= shirt_color.hex %>" 
   data-price="<%= product.base_price %>" 
   data-product-id="<%= product.id %>">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the click handler for the link element?

You can do the following in jQuery: first add a click hander to the link:

```
$("a.shirt-color-link").on("click", function(){
   calculatePrice($(this));
})
```

Then in `calculatePrice` add argument `obj` and replace `var blankPrice = 5;` with:

```
var blankPrice = obj.attr("data-price");
```

`obj` refers to the clicked link and it's `data-attributes`.

Comment: so i edited to your answer. Im just a bit unclear about the obj and how to assign it.

Comment: function calculatePrice(obj)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.shirt-color-link').attr("data-price", blankPrice);
```

EDIT - this is changing the "data-price" attribute to be whatever the value of the blankPrice variable is.  You might want it the other way round, on reading again (it's a bit unclear), in which case do

```
var blankPrice = parseInt($('.shirt-color-link').attr("data-price"));
```

Comment: Don't forget the `radix` ;-)

Comment: What @Mouser means is that when using `parseInt()`, proper practice is to pass the second `radix` argument in to tell it what base to use in the conversion.  I tend to not bother which is a bit naughty:  some browsers (or other clients) might not convert it properly otherwise.  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: You naughty boy ;-), like me you like to live dangerously. I try to include it nowadays, since I first read about it.